# Name does not exist in current context inside typeahead select

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I have the following code:

```
       }).on("typeahead:select", function (e, copy) {


            if (@Model.statusMap[copy.Id] === "Checked Out")
            {
                bootbox.alert("This copy is checked out. Please choose another copy.");
            }
```

I am trying to check to see if the copy id that the user selected is in the dictionary or not. Why am I getting the context error here and how can I fix this?

**"The name copy does not exist in the current context"**

However, if I do let's say if(copy.Id == "something"), then it works fine. It just doesnt work inside the statusMap dictionary.

Comment: Can you show more of the code, specifically where `savedCopy` is initialized, and in what scope?

Comment: Please look at the code again. I have removed savedCopy and just directly called the "copy" parameter. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Ah. I think the jQuery `on` function only gets a single `e` argument passed to it. I think you can use whats in the `e` event detail to get `copy`.

Comment: I tried this:    if (@Model.statusMap[e.copy.Id]).. but am getting the same context error saying e does not exist.

Comment: Anyone? I am still struggling with this man